# GCP multi-region snapshot: Are multiple copies of the snapshot stored in different regions?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, snapshot

GCP support different snapshot storage locations like multi-region location or region location.
If snapshot is stored in multi-region location, then does this mean that multiple copies of the same snapshot would be stored in all the regions that are associated with the "selected" multi-region location. For example if snapshot is stored in multi-region location "us", would GCP store multiple redundant copies of the same snapshot in all the regions that comes under "multi-region location us?"

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. You can see only one snapshot but, behind the scene, the snapshot are replicated.

Multi-region means "at least 3 regions". Therefore, multi region US, doesn't mean, in all US region, only 3